# Telerik RadNotificationMessage does not maintain page scroll position in IE8

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

My `Default.aspx` code

```
<telerik:RadNotification ID="rnMsg" runat="server" AutoCloseDelay="5000" 
    Enabled="True" Position="BottomRight" Skin="Vista"
    EnableShadow="True" EnableViewState="False" VisibleTitlebar="True">
</telerik:RadNotification>
```

When I scroll the page little down and click a button, the RadNotification message is displayed in the center and not in the bottom of the page where I set the `Position="BottomRight"`. Help me to solve this issue. Thanks.

**Update**: Working Fine in IE9, Chrome and Firefox but **not working** in **IE8**

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your code-behind to see if you are modifying the Position property there? Code-behind takes precedence over markup.

I've seen similar problems, check if this is your case too:
http://www.telerik.com/support/pits.aspx#/public/aspnet-ajax/13087
If so - try disabling the animations, it seems to help.

Comment: It is working fine in Chrome and Firefox. But it is **not working** in **IE9**

Comment: I checked the document mode in IE and it is pointed to IE8 and when I switched over to IE9 mode, it is working fine as expected. I think the problem persists in IE 8. I also updated my question as not working in IE8. Thanks.

Comment: Is only the documents mode IE8? BOth browser mode and document mode should be the same, otherwise you'll get some mixed results and rendering. The Telerik controls rely quite a lot on browser feature detection and the document mode can confuse that if it does not match the browser mode.